# RestKit relationShip fatal issue with core data [__NSCFBoolean isDeleted]

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have an issue with restKit/core data. I had working app without using core data in it. Everything worked fine. But when I translate everything on core data rails my app started to fall. Some search gave me thought that problem in `relationshipMappingFromKeyPath` because without this everything works perfectly.

[my core data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfL5E.png)

[my json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eseui.png)

my code:

`NSString *URLPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/v1/projects/%ld/tasks", projectId];

NSDictionary *mappingDictionary = @{

                                    @"id"                : @"taskId",
                                    @"attrs.state"       : @"state",
                                    @"attrs.priority"    : @"priority",
                                    @"attrs.title"       : @"title",
                                    @"attrs.createdAt"   : @"createdAt",
                                    @"attrs.finishedAt"  : @"finishedAt",
                                    @"attrs.problem"     : @"problem",
                                    @"attrs.solution"    : @"solution",
                                    @"attrs.spent"       : @"spent",
                                    @"attrs.complete"    : @"complete"

                                    };

NSDictionary *taskSolutionDictionary = @{

                                         @"fileName"     : @"fileName",
                                         @"URL"          : @"urlString",

                                         };

RKEntityMapping *taskMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"SMTask"
                                                   inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
[taskMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingDictionary];

RKEntityMapping *taskSolutionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"SMTaskSolutionFile"
                                                           inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
[taskSolutionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:taskSolutionDictionary];


[taskMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"related.subtasks"
                                                                            toKeyPath:@"subTasks"
                                                                          withMapping:taskMapping]];


[taskMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"attrs.solutionFiles"
                                                                            toKeyPath:@"solutionFiles"
                                                                          withMapping:taskSolutionMapping]];

NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:taskMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                   pathPattern:URLPath
                                                                                       keyPath:@"data"
                                                                                   statusCodes:statusCodes];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSMutableDictionary *resultParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@(page) forKey:@"page"];
[resultParams addEntriesFromDictionary:params];`

But each time I have this error:

> 2016-06-16 18:31:27.286 InterLabs[53443:10207583] I
>   restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:137 GET
>   https: //api.interlabs.pro/v1/projects/3o7/tasks?page=1 2016-06-16
>   18:31:27.351 InterLabs[53443:10207568] I
>   restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances
>   of Entity 'SMTask' by attributes 'taskId' 2016-06-16 18:31:27.578
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.580
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.582
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.587
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.590
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.590
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.591
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.592
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.594
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.595
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.596
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.597
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.621
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.622
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.624
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.629
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1. 2016-06-16 18:31:27.631
>   InterLabs[53443:10207568] W
>   restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:286
>   Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured
>   for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1.
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean isDeleted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108860420'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001085b6f35 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108251bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001085be04d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010851627c ___forwarding_** + 988
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108515e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   InterLabs                           0x00000001057992a3 -[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource mappingOperation:targetObjectForRepresentation:withMapping:inRelationship:] + 2659
>       6   InterLabs                           0x00000001057bfb84 -[RKMappingOperation destinationObjectForMappingRepresentation:parentRepresentation:withMapping:inRelationship:] + 1604
>       7   InterLabs                           0x00000001057c5905 __64-[RKMappingOperation mapOneToManyRelationshipWithValue:mapping:]_block_invoke + 117
>       8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001085179c4 __NSArrayEnumerate + 596
>       9   InterLabs                           0x00000001057c5390 -[RKMappingOperation mapOneToManyRelationshipWithValue:mapping:] + 2240
>       10  InterLabs                           0x00000001057c70d7 -[RKMappingOperation applyRelationshipMappings] + 5223
>       11  InterLabs                           0x00000001057c8f2b -[RKMappingOperation main] + 3627
>       12  InterLabs                           0x00000001057c80eb -[RKMappingOperation start] + 43
>       13  InterLabs                           0x00000001057b874b -[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentation:toObject:isNew:atKeyPath:usingMapping:metadataList:] + 1723
>       14  InterLabs                           0x00000001057b7e50 __63-[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentations:atKeyPath:usingMapping:]_block_invoke + 336
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001085179c4 __NSArrayEnumerate + 596
>       16  InterLabs                           0x00000001057b7b81 -[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentations:atKeyPath:usingMapping:] + 2705
>       17  InterLabs                           0x00000001057b9b5b -[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentationOrRepresentations:atKeyPath:usingMapping:] + 459
>       18  InterLabs                           0x00000001057ba469 -[RKMapperOperation mapSourceRepresentationWithMappingsDictionary:] + 1945
>       19  InterLabs                           0x00000001057badd1 -[RKMapperOperation main] + 1457
>       20  Foundation                          0x0000000107db5384 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
>       21  InterLabs                           0x000000010580bf27 __73-[RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation performMappingWithObject:error:]_block_invoke + 4743
>       22  CoreData                            0x0000000105f9df06 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 198
>       23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001093a17f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109388774 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365
>       25  CoreData                            0x0000000105f9ddd6 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 230
>       26  InterLabs                           0x000000010580a84a -[RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation performMappingWithObject:error:] + 1082
>       27  InterLabs                           0x00000001058083ff -[RKResponseMapperOperation main] + 2287
>       28  Foundation                          0x0000000107db5384 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
>       29  Foundation                          0x0000000107db4f93 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
>       30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001093a17f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109389b22 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1417
>       32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109389432 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
>       33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010938bfc1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 685
>       34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010938d5d9 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
>       35  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010970e4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
>       36  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010970c341 start_wqthread + 13
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: show the JSON, the core data model and the log output just before the crash

Comment: I aded json and core data like images in the question. And added full log. @Wain

Comment: You need to fix your unique identifiers to prevent `Managed object cache returned 9 objects for the identifier configured for the 'SMTask' entity, expected 1`. It isn't clear where the booleans are currently...

Comment: I commented `taskMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"taskId"];` And now I have `2016-06-16 18:56:04.659 InterLabs[53797:10293553] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:137 GET 'https://api.interlabs.pro/v1/projects/307/tasks?page=1'
2016-06-16 18:56:04.767 InterLabs[53797:10293553] -[__NSCFBoolean isDeleted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107475420
2016-06-16 18:56:04.782 InterLabs[53797:10293553] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean isDeleted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107475420'
` @Wain

Comment: so it looks to be treating a boolean NSNumber as a managed object, but I can't tell why from the information available